# blink-cursor-mode with nicer blinking?

Tags: emacs

Blinking cursors can be quite irritating. It is easy to switch blinking off with `blink-cursor-mode` (or maybe customize it ...). But with larger screens, it is often difficult to locate the cursor-position. So, well, blinking might make sense after all.

However, what is visually very irritating is that blinking is done by switching between a full rectangle (or bar) and nothing. When you now compare <kbd>C-x 3</kbd> like side-by-side two buffers, the selected buffer has sometimes the rectangle and sometimes not. So you cannot easily look to one side and then the other ; you have to wait for the cursor to "reappear". That is very irritating.

So my question is: Is it possible have blinking switch between full-rectangle and something related? Lighter-colored rectangle? It should not be hollow-rectangle because this is used in the other buffer.

(I am using 23.1)

Comment: Have you reviewed [this](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Cursor-Display.html)?

Comment: @false Take a look at `M-x global-hl-line-mode` together with cursor blinking disabled.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is possible from 24.1 on.

The [`blink-cursor-alist`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Cursor-Display.html) permits to specify for each `on-type` an `off-type`.

Thanks to @RobertHarvey for pointing this out.